# Swift URLSession doesn't behave like Curl or HTTParty

Tags: swift, curl, httparty

**Background**
I am working on a swift project with `particle.io` setup two legged auth part. Basically it's a POST request.

My issue is I can get the correct response by `CURL` and `HTTParty. (Like below) but with`URLSession` the response is 404.

By **CURL**

```
curl -X POST -u "abcd:secret" -d password=true -d email="wwsd@gmail.com" https://api.particle.io/v1/orgs/xxx/customers
```

By **HTTParty**

```
require 'HTTParty'
def register_spark_two_legged_user(query)
   return HTTParty.post("https://api.particle.io/v1/orgs/xxx/customers", body: query, basic_auth:{"username":"abcd","password":"secret"}) 
end

query = {"email":"wwsd@gmail.com", "no_password":true}
json = register_spark_two_legged_user query
p json
```

I want to do it in Swift:

```
func twoLegged() {
        let urlString = "https://api.particle.io/v1/orgs/xxx/customers"
        let parameters = ["email":"wwsd@gmail.com","no_password":true] as [String : Any]
        let userName = "abcd"
        let password = "secret"
        let loginString = userName+":"+password
        let loginData = loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedString()

        let url = URL(string: urlString)!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        do {
           request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:   parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)
        } catch let error {
           print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
        if let e = error {
            print(e.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
            debugPrint(response as Any)
            print(json)
        }
       }.resume()
```

Did I miss something? Thanks for the help. Here's a link might useful: [community.particle.io](https://community.particle.io/t/creating-a-new-customer-two-legged-auth-now-working/14825)

**EDIT** I changed the httpBody still the same not work.

```
var comp = URLComponents()
        comp.queryItems = [
            URLQueryItem(name: "no_password", value: "true"),
            URLQueryItem(name: "email", value: "wwsd@gmail.com"),
        ]
        request.httpBody = comp.query?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencode", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

The output is

```
Optional({
    error = "Not Found";
    ok = 0;
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `curl` you are sending the data out as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, i.e. in the form

```
no_password=true&email=wwsd@gmail.com
```

But in Swift you are sending off the data as JSON.

```
request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)
# wrong: form data is expected, not JSON.
```

---

You could format to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` using `URLComponents` and `URLQueryItem`:

```
var comp = URLComponents()
comp.queryItems = [
    URLQueryItem(name: "no_password", value: "true"),
    URLQueryItem(name: "email", value: "wwsd@gmail.com"),
]
request.httpBody = comp.query?.data(using: .utf8)
```

---

Also you did not pass the request into URLSession...

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { ... }
//                               ^~~~~~~ you were passing `url`.
```

Comment: Another problem is that you are not allowed to set the Authorization header, per Apple's documentation.  The right way to do this is to provide a delegate and include an authentication method that returns the correct credentials; if you need a quick temporary solution, you could add an Internet Password to the keychain.

Comment: Hi @kennytm, i tried `URLComponents` also i added `application/x-www-form-urlencode` as request header filed still the same result. See my edit. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `Optional({
    error = "Not Found";
    ok = 0;
})`

Comment: The curl and HTTParty out put is `{"ok":false,"code":400,"error":"customer_exists"}` or `{"token_type":"bearer","access_token":"7d35239f45b3b3f32423beecf7ab5117dfdc822f","expires_in":7776000,"refresh_token":"3b23e4062351b3c639584a0b78893a8320e4880c","scope":"customer=wwsd@gmail.com"}`

Comment: Oh my! I must be drunk last night. Shame! 谢谢！